# POST request in VBA using excel data

Tags: excel, vba, api, post

Please take into consideration that I am new and never worked in VBA that's why the available tutorial is also not working for me.

I know how to write post requests in Python. I am doing it according to the following code:

```
import requests
response = requests.post(url= API_ENDPOINT ,json={"data": data_for_test, "stream_key": 'stream_key', "return_data": "False"})
```

Now I want to send the same post request defined in Python using a VBA.  So far I have tried following:

```
Sub macroPOST()
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = "[API_ENDPOINT]"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    Set json_dict = New Dictionary 'Declaring a new dict

    json_dict("stream_key") = Range("B1").Value  'Taking value from excel
    json_dict("return_data") = Range("B3").Value  ' From excel

    Set dict = ex_dictD(Range("G4:I8")) 'Creating a dict from excel data similar to python data dictionary

    json_dict.Add "data", dict ' Adding to json

    TempTxt = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(json_dict) ' Finally generating a json from dict

    ' A sample json as follows: TempTxt ={"stream_key":"stream_key","return_data":false,"data":{""price"":"[40000,8000,8000,8000]",""furnishingstatus"":"[furnished,unfurnished,unfurnished,semi-furnished]",""basement"":"[yes,no,no,yes]"}}

    objHTTP.Open "POST", Url, False
    objHTTP.send TempTxt
    If objHTTP.Status = "200" Then 'success
        MsgBox replyTXT
    Else
        'Do something
    End If
End Sub
```

Until now I am not successful.  My final goal is to use that post request function as a Macro button. Please help me if you can.

Comment: You got an error or something?

Comment: You've done `objHTTP.Open` twice. You should only do it once.

Comment: `replyTXT` isn't being set to anything, so the messagebox will be blank. You probably meant `objHTTP.responseText `.

Comment: It depends on the website you're interacting with, but you may need to set some headers, often the Authorization or API key is given as a header. But not always, one of the services I use expects the API key inside the body as a data value.

Comment: "I am not successful" doesn't tell us anything about what happens when you run your code.   Why are property names inside of `data` double-quoted?

Comment: @Toddleson Thanks for pointing it out. But that was a typing mistake. I have found the solution

I have just missed ```objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"``` line

Answer (score 0):

I was very close to my solution. In my code I was missing following part : `objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"`

SO my final solution is

```
Sub macroPOST()
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim Url As String
    Dim data As Dictionary

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    Set json_dict = New Dictionary
    
    Set data_dict = New Dictionary 'Creating a new dictionary from a table of excel where the Headers are G5, H5 and I5 .
    data_dict(Range("G5").Value) = Range("G6:G8").Value
    data_dict(Range("H5").Value) = Range("H6:H8").Value
    data_dict(Range("I5").Value) = Range("I6:I8").Value


    json_dict("stream_key") = Range("B1").Value 'Taking value from excel
    json_dict("return_data") = "False"
    json_dict("env") = Range("B4").Value 'Taking value from excel
    
    json_dict.Add "data", data_dict ' Adding dictionary of data to another dictionary. 
    
    TempTxt = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(json_dict) ' Finally generating a json from dict
    
    Debug.Print TempTxt
    Url = Range("B2").Value
    
    objHTTP.Open "POST", Url, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json" 'Here is the part I was missing at the time of posting my answer. I need to define json if I send my data as json
    objHTTP.send TempTxt      
    If objHTTP.Status = "200" Then 'success
    Else
        'Do something
    End If
    Debug.Print objHTTP.responseText
End Sub
```